# Can I enforce constraints set in OpenApiCustomiser to regular API calls?

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

In my Spring project, I use OpenAPI 3 definitions for my api docs, derived from Gradle springdoc-openapi-ui library:

```
compile group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.0'
```

There are constraints that I set from the Swagger Config, including default length and pattern for those not custom set at the lower level, as seen below:

```
    public int setStringContraints(Schema schema){
        if(schema.getMaxLength() == null){
            schema.setMaxLength(255);
        }
        if(schema.getPattern() == null){
            schema.setPattern("^.*$");
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This enforces the maximum length in my Swagger UI. For example, using ID path variable "11111...<256+ chars>" will result in the API command not firing and highlight the invalid ID.

However, if I try the same ID as the path variable in my browser, the API function still executes. Is it possible to enforce the OpenAPI restriction on the actual server as well?